# Does NetworkManager have a limited bandwidth mode?

Tags: network-manager, mobile-broadband

As soon as I go online via my portable 3G hotspot, all running programs happily start pulling updates (e.g. Gwibber, Thunderbird, Update Manager...) and eat into my traffic quota. Is there a way to activate a network connection, but only tell specific programs about it (e.g. Firefox, if I just want to quickly look something up)? Note that I'm not looking for bandwidth limiting, I just want to prevent the automatic "ooh, I'm online, let's get some data" behavior.

EDIT: I have already received two useful answers, however, I'd still like to add some clarification: what does NetworkManager do to tell running programs they're now online? I assume it's some sort of DBus message. Can I prevent that from being sent?

Comment: Networkmanager has an option for metered connections which _should_ be honored by applications listening to network-state-changed on dbus.
Setting this to 'no' for home-wifi, and 'yes' for mobile-3g should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways that I would do that is using a Firewall.  Ubuntu comes with it own Firewall [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW).  You might want to install the GUI version, just to make it easier.  To install it,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

Once it finishes, just type gufw at the terminal prompt, and with the application opens, click on Edit, and then Add Rule.

[image]

When that window opens, choose Deny --> Out --> Application -->, and then choose the application that you want.  For command line control over the Firewall, see [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

[image]

If you want to block e.g. DropBox, you can block the entire Dropbox network IP allocation listed in [ARIN](http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/DROPB/nets), as seen in the image below.

[image]

And you can see that it keeps saying connecting..

[image]

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, ufw can only block some BitTorrent clients or Skype, not e.g. Dropbox.

Comment: Look at the info I added regarding Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved if we restrict application **from AUTOMATIC PULL** configuration.  Example for Update Manager

[image]

Similarly you may configure for other applications like:

**Disabling Automatic Update in Firefox**

Type *about:config* in the address bar and press Enter.

You should get a page trying to scare you off with a message starting with **“This might void you warranty!”, just click “I’ll be careful I promise!“**.

Then in the Filter filed type *app.update.enabled*. It should be set to true, double-click on the line to set it to false.
  **Disabling Automatic update for Thunderbird**
On the top menu, click on Tools->Options to enter the Options window,
   then click on Advanced and selct the General tab. Click on the Config Editor

You should get a page trying to scare you off with a message starting with **“This might void you warranty!”, just click “I’ll be careful I promise!“**.

Then in the Filter filed type *app.update.enabled*. It should be set to true, double-click on the line to set it to false.

**Upgrades on preferred network**

Referring to the man-pages of [Network Switcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic#Define_tests_to_select_networks)
You may have certain commands configured when you are on the 3Ghotspot/Homewifi.
For an instance for thunderbird upgrades you may change the prefs.js(specific to user profile) or syspref.js(globally) to enable the update option.

So your would look like /etc/network/interfaces

```
# Home Wifi
iface homewifi inet static
  # Set the DNS entry
  dns-domain something.net.com
  dns-search some.net yes.something.net www.somesite.com
  # Set the sysprefs.js entries for update.
  script /usr/sbin/which_edits_the_sysprefs.sh
```

We may add anything we want to have the same executed on a specific network.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for a way to disable updates and similar stuff only when I'm on mobile broadband. I'm ok with automatic updates as long as I'm on my home wifi.

Comment: Could you please have a look on the part for upgrades on preferred network.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty close. Any way to do that for NetworkManager (whose networks are not defined in /etc/network/interfaces)?

Comment: BTW, are you sure you can use "pref(...)" in /etc/network/interfaces? AFAICT it's not a Javascript file.

Comment: Yes, pref wont right away work, we may initiate the script command for the same as edited on my response above.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my edited question myself: NetworkManager indeed sends a DBus signal which looks as follows:

```
signal sender=:1.6 -> dest=(null destination) serial=2031 path=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager; interface=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager; member=StateChanged
uint32 70
```

NM-aware programs listen to this message and react to it by starting to use the network. No way to prevent this without hacking on NM directly AFAICT.